# Rewrite URLs in .htaccess for replacing Query parameters with forward slash (id?=value)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I have made sure that rewrite engine is enabled and removing .php extensions is working so I know that isn't the issue.

what I'm trying to do is simply remove the ?id=value aspect of the URL, so basically making the URL look like such:

```
folder/medias/value
```

Instead of

```
folder/medias?id=value
```

My current .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^404/?$ /404.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^ 404.php [L,R]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your code. Could you please do let us know what URL you are hitting on browser?

Comment: Thanks I'm just trying to figure out how to display the page {domain}/folder/medias?id=Banks as  {domain}/folder/medias/Banks

Comment: Thanks, is media a folder? OR a php file?

Comment: Media is a php file where i am using this query value

Comment: So basically you will hit in browser like `http://localhost:80/folder/medias.php?d=Banks` which should be changed to `http://localhost:80/folder/medias/Banks` correct?

Comment: Yes, need this http://localhost:80/folder/medias/Banks

Comment: Sure, I have posted an answer now, we could further discuss in its comments section.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for external rewrite.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.php\?id=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
##Rule for internal rewrite.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1?id=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this code inside the `/folder/.htaccess` (create this file if it doesn't exist):

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# External redirect from /folder/media?id=val to /folder/media/val
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(\S+?)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

# Internal rewrite from /folder/media/val to /folder/media?id=val
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

- Trailing `?` in first rule is to remove query string from original URL.
- `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is to skip existing files and directories from rewrite in 2nd rule.